# How to control qsplitter handle using buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QSplitter` with 2 widgets, and I want to control which widget is shown using buttons. 
One for the "left" one, one for the "right" one, and the third for both.

1. How can i make it possible to control the width of the widgets by
   the user, and to give him a shorter way of doing this.
2. How can I change the style of the `Qsplitterhandle` ? now it has the same style/shape/color as the
   background, so it is impossible to see the `Qsplitterhandle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse and uncollapse a `QSplitter` programmatically using [`setSizes`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#setSizes). Connecting each of the following slots to your buttons should do the trick.

```
def onLeft(self):
    self.splitter.setSizes([1, 0])

def onBoth(self):
    self.splitter.setSizes([1, 1])

def onRight(self):
    self.splitter.setSizes([0, 1])
```

If you want to change the style of your QSplitter handle, you could use [StyleSheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qsplitter).

```
stylesheet = "QSplitter::handle{background: gray; width: 2px; height: 2px;}"
self.splitter.setStyleSheet(stylesheet )
```